# Import Error: Problem with importing from Python Package

Tags: python, import

> 

```
import audiolabel 
import numpy as np

from ultramisc import ebutils as eb
from audiolabel import LabelManager



ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-2387500242d1> in <module>
      4 
      5 from ultramisc import ebutils as eb
----> 6 from audiolabel import LabelManager

ImportError: cannot import name 'LabelManager' from 'audiolabel' (unknown location)

In [39]:
```

I'm trying to import LabelManager from the audiolabel package I got using git clone but for some reason there is no way to import LabelManager? I'm not sure why this is the case, because from all the documentation I've seen from audiolabel, they are able to import LabelManager

Answer (score 0):

This error could be caused by multiple reasons...
Have you tried downloading via pip install ?

```
pip3 install "git+https://github.com/rsprouse/audiolabel.git"
```

Comment: Yes. I tried it, and it says it was successfully built, the package works but im not sure about why it cant import the label manager. The unknown location part is weird to me

Comment: Ok this happened to me once.
I renamed my python file name It held the same package name.
try to change it or look for python files you created holding names like LabelManager.py

Comment: Try to rename your .py files